# In VBA is it possible to get the value of a button on a worksheet which is stored as a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, button, compiler-errors

In VBA is there a way to refer to a button on a worksheet that's held as a variable? Unless I refer to the sheet directly it seems to throw a compile error for "Method or data member not found". So for example:

```
Sub Test_Parent
    Call Test_Child(Temp_WS:=Sheet1)
End Sub

Sub Test_Child(ByVal Temp_WS as Worksheet)
    debug.print Temp_WS.Example_Button.Value
End Sub
```

The above triggers the error on the debug.print line. Whereas the following works without issue:

```
Sub Test2
    debug.print Sheet1.Example_Button.Value
End Sub
```

My gut says that this is because in the second case the compiler looks at a direct reference (e.g. Sheet1) and can see that the button exists as a member, whereas in the first case it looks at the variable and views it as a generic worksheet type (rather than being Sheet1) and so doesn't think there would be this member? Or maybe I'm completely off the mark?

Either way, is there a way around it? (Or am I doing something stupid for that matter?) If not it's not the end of the world, but I typically like to minimise the number of hard-coded references to sheets so if this is a way to resolve it then that would be great.

Comment: `ByVal Temp_WS as Object` maybe.

Comment: That's done it! Any idea why that might be the case? (Also, if you submit that as an answer I'll accept it :) )

Comment: `Worksheet` is a specific built-in class in Excel, and that class does not have a property named `Example_Button` - this is what triggers the compile error.  Whereas `Object` is a more general type which may or may not have an `Example_Button` property - there's no way to know at compile time, so the check is deferred to run-time, and will pass as long as the argument does have the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Example_Button`, as an `ActiveX` `OLEObject` is a member of `Sheet1` and it can be referenced as `Sheet1.Example_Button`.

But it is also an `OLEObject` and a `shape`, too.

You cannot find it as a member of the general `Worksheet` object. You can use the `Sub` as you try, generally declaring the parameter `As Variant` (or `As Object`), passing the `Sheet1` class itself:

```
Sub Test_Child(ByVal Temp_WS as Variant)
    Debug.Print Temp_WS.Example_Button.Value
End Sub
```

And this will work. Practically, declaring `As Variant` or `As Object` it simulates the next `Sub`, which allows declaring he parameter as the involved sheet class. The single one exposing the object in the way you try:

```
Sub Test_ChildSheetSh1(ByVal Temp_WS As Sheet1)
    Debug.Print Temp_WS.Example_Button.Value
End Sub
```

But better approaches are to use the object as `OLEObject` or as `shape`, which works for `Worksheet` object, too:

```
Sub Test_ChildOLE(ByVal Temp_WS as Worksheet)
    Debug.Print Temp_WS.OLEObjects("Example_Button").Object.Value
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Test_ChildSh(ByVal Temp_WS As Worksheet)
    Debug.Print Temp_WS.Shapes("Example_Button").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
End Sub
```

You can event use `Worksheet` for a `Form` type button (not an `ActiveX`) in the next way:

```
Sub Test_ChildForm(ByVal Temp_WS As Worksheet)
    Debug.Print Temp_WS.Shapes("Example_Button").OLEFormat.Object.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: One more which works with `ByVal Temp_WS As Worksheet`:  `Debug.Print CallByName(Temp_WS, "Example_Button", VbGet).Value`

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes, I love this function... It's another way to extract the object from `Worksheet` and use its properties. The working subs directly using `Temp_WS.Example_Button.Value` are only the ones simulating `Test_Child(ByVal Temp_WS As Sheet1)`. I think (now) that it would be good to edit my answer and state that...